# Large File Upload Fails with JMeter

Tags: curl, file-upload, jmeter, httprequest

I am trying to use Apache JMeter to test a server's performance in a file upload scenario. Specifically, I am using the HTTP Test Script Recorder to create a test plan to realize this curl command:

```
$ curl -k -x localhost:8888 -XPOST -d @filename.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://hostname:port"
```

I have had success with this method before when filename.json was only several dozen lines long, but now when I want to test a json with roughly 72,000 lines (a ~5.1M file), I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:876)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:847)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.writeTo(StringEntity.java:169)
at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:216)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.sendRequestEntity(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:207)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:619)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:379)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:240)
```

Indeed, I believe this problem lies with JMeter somehow, because the raw curl command that doesn't involve JMeter

```
curl -XPOST -d @filename.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://hostname:port"
```

uploads the file without a hitch.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check first that your file is in jmeter/bin folder

Then check that you are using JMeter best practices ?

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

And give more details in your question on your test plan and test methodology

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this test with multiple users or a single thread?

Check the memory allocated to JMeter and try to increase in case you are running this with multiple users.
Make sure the file is being picked. Ideally the file to be uploaded should reside under bin folder. Also check the headers you are sending while uploading the file.

Also check if there is any authorization id that needs to be passed along with file. 
One of these should help solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Simply inputting this curl command while the test script recorder is running gives me this error. I believe it has to do with the entire 72k line file being loaded into the body data tab, which is overloading the memory. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I didnt understand the curl command part? Can you explain how are you recording it? You can send the json file as an attachment with http sampler.